# Mootools to jquery object issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I am converting a Mootools snip to jQuery and have an issue with value being returned as an object.

Mootools code

```
aVariable: function (elems, locks, hiddenInput, elem) {
    initialValue = '';
    if (elem) {
        var val = elem.get('value').toFloat().round(2);
        var v = val ? val : '0';
        elem.set({
            'value': v
        });
        Serialize.verifyInput(elems, elem, locks);
    }
}
```

jquery bad try

```
aVariable: function (elems, locks, hiddenInput, elem) {
    initialValue = '';
    if (elem) {
        var val = $(elem).get('value').toFloat().round(2);
        var v = val ? val : '0';
        $(elem).val(v);
        Serialize.verifyInput(elems, elem, locks);
    }
}
```

I know that $(elem)  or $(this) returns an object where in Moo elem returns the string
can someone shed some light on this please. 
Thank you!

Comment: It's `$(elem).val()`, assuming you have a `toFloat()` and `round() ` method ?

Comment: isnt round default js ? i have no additional methods , like said just converting to jq and that one line is bugging me , var val = $(elem).get('value').toFloat().round(2);

Comment: and toFloat() in Moo returns number as a float. http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Number#Number:toFloat

Comment: Then you're probably looking for `parseFloat` and `Math.round` / `toFixed` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know, jQuery and Mootools can exist in the same page, anyway to answer your question, try this:

```
aVariable: function (elems, locks, hiddenInput, elem) {
    initialValue = '';
    var round = function (inputValue, precision) {
        precision = Math.pow(10, precision || 0).toFixed(precision < 0 ? -precision : 0);
        return Math.round(inputValue * precision) / precision;
    }
    if (elem) {
        var val = round(parseFloat(elem.value),2);
        var v = val ? val : '0';
        elem.value = v;
        Serialize.verifyInput(elems, elem, locks);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same issue with the object Object 5 has no method 'round'

Comment: @Benn, yes, sorry. Updated answer. You might have to look for more `.round()` in your code and replace it.

Comment: well close enough ,  the round was suppose to limit max 2 numbers in input. yes i know about moo and jq , the script is actually a mix of both and I want to convert it to jq only( maintenance issue )

Comment: @Benn, what do you mean "close enough" ? Here are the original Mootools for those functions: http://jsfiddle.net/LPn7b/